# xcode twitter api authorize screen issue

Tags: objective-c, ios7, twitter-oauth

I have an app that I'm using the xcode IDE and writing in Objective-C that uses the twitter api and the 'default' twitter login page for username and password.

I already have all the oauth stuff set up and it is working fine.

I create a new view controller with a web view inside it, and pass the URL of `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize`.

If I put in my email and password, everything works fine - the view disappears, and we are then off and running.

If I press cancel on the twitter login screen, I get a twitter page saying I need to log in. I need to capture the `cancel` in my code so I can dismiss the view controller, but I cannot find out what the name of the callback is? I tried `didFailLoadWithError` but that is not it.

Can someone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it can be handled from the same callback that handles a 'correct' login. except looking for a failure.
So, they have handled it correctly within the original callback.